# os module python is working but the output isn't correct

Tags: python, bash

I decided to read name files and create soft links for files in python.

I tried to use `os.system` for create soft links, this creates link files but after opening the link file says  "this file not found"

```
os.system(f'ln -s "./../{movie_name}" "./../sorted/{year}/{movie_name}"')
```

and use `os.symlink(f'./../{filename}',f'./../{filename}.link')`

and when open this link file not founded.

Comment: Why `os.system()`? The same module has a [`os.symlink()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.symlink).

Comment: Symlinks can always be created, it doesn't matter if the destination exists. We can't help fix this because we don't know anything about your filesystem, what needs to link to what.

Comment: And last but not least, you created a symlink that points to a path that starts with `"./../"`. The path is *not resolved to an absolute path first*. If the movie name is a directory in the *same directory as `sorted`, then that's the wrong path and you would need to add an additional `../` component.

Comment: when file created and i open it is says The operation can’t be completed because the original item for 'filename' can’t be found.

Answer (score 4):

Please use `os.symlink()` to create symlinks instead, don't shell out to `ln -s`. After all, as it is your problem may be caused by improper quoting (consider a movie name with a quote, for instance).

In addition, remember symlinks can contain relative paths. You can canonicalize the destination path with `os.path.realpath()`:

```py
source_name = os.path.realpath(f"../{movie_name}")
dest_name = f"../sorted/{year}/{movie_name}"
assert os.path.isfile(source_name)  # just to be sure!
os.symlink(source_name, dest_name)
```

Comment: Relative paths in symlinks are fine, as long as you accept that they are relative to the *location of the symlink*. Relative paths make it easier to relocate the whole structure.

Comment: Sure. `os.path.relpath()` is an option too :)

Comment: But to be explicit: you would have to then use `os.path.realpath(dest_name)` as the second argument to `os.path.relpath()`.